# How do I create new entries in a json file

Tags: python, json, discord

I am trying to create a discord bot using python that can create and update user profiles. I'm just now learning python and json and it's not sinking in. What would a function look like if I wanted to open the existing profiles.json file and add a new profile into it. Here's what I have so far:

```
def new_profile(p_id, p_name):
  p_new = {'profile':[{'id': p_id, 'name': p_name, 'level': '1', 'xp': '0'}]}
  with open('profile.json') as outfile:
    data = json.load(outfile)

  ##need some code here to append?

  with open('profile.json','w') as outfile:
    
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your `profile.json` file content is:

```
{"profile":[{"id":123,"name":"john","level":"1","xp":"0"}]}
```

the below should do the trick:

```
import json

def new_profile(p_id, p_name):
    p_new = {'id': p_id, 'name': p_name, 'level': '1', 'xp': '0'}
    
    with open('profile.json', 'r') as outfile:
        data = json.load(outfile)
        data['profile'].append(p_new)

    with open('profile.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)

new_profile(321, 'kate')
```

profile.json:

```
{"profile": [{"id": 123, "name": "john", "level": "1", "xp": "0"}, {"id": 321, "name": "kate", "level": "1", "xp": "0"}]}
```